# Visual Studio Code - ssh remotehost extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I can connect with the remote explorer to a linux machine.
In the config file I have set it up like this:

```
Host Scripting_enms_ansadm1
  HostName henms-haproxy.sharedtcs.net
  User test1
  ForwardAgent yes
  Port 5023
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile C:\\Users\\tolstr01\\.ssh\\vscode
```

This is working perfectly fine.
But I would like to connect directly to a diffrent directory, at the moment it jumps to the home directory.

I search for something like this, with the **RemotePath**

```
Host Scripting_enms_ansadm1
  HostName henms-haproxy.sharedtcs.net
  User test1
  ForwardAgent yes
  Port 5023
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile C:\\Users\\tolstr01\\.ssh\\vscode
  RemotePath /home/shared/common/scripts/
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `RemotePath` is not in the [ssh config file format](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html).
A possible hack is to modify your `.bashrc` file on the remote host and add detection of your connection from a certain IP, and change directory if that's the case:

```bash
# Change directory to /home/shared/common/scripts/ when connecting from 192.168.1.100
if [[ $SSH_CLIENT =~ ^192.168.1.100 ]]; then
  cd /home/shared/common/scripts/
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint @matleg
Do you know if I can tell VSCode to open a other default folder?
Now it opens /home/shared/ansadm1/
Best regards, Roland